# can't get the Jest provided ESM example to run

Tags: jestjs, mocking, es6-modules

I'm just trying to get the [ES6 Class Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks) example provided by Jest to run green.

here's my [code repo](https://github.com/jasonrberk/jest-mocking-esm)

it's taken me *way* to long to even get to this point, but the tests still fail with

`TypeError: SoundPlayer.mockClear is not a function`

system under test

```
import SoundPlayer from './sound-player';

export default class SoundPlayerConsumer {
    constructor() {
        this.soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
    }

    playSomethingCool() {
        const coolSoundFileName = 'song.mp3';
        this.soundPlayer.playSoundFile(coolSoundFileName);
    }
}
```

the test

```
import {jest} from '@jest/globals';
import SoundPlayer from './sound-player';
import SoundPlayerConsumer from './sound-player-consumer';

const mockPlaySoundFile = jest.fn();
jest.mock('./sound-player', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {playSoundFile: mockPlaySoundFile};
  });
});

beforeEach(() => {
  SoundPlayer.mockClear();
  mockPlaySoundFile.mockClear();
});

it('The consumer should be able to call new() on SoundPlayer', () => {
  const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer();
  // Ensure constructor created the object:
  expect(soundPlayerConsumer).toBeTruthy();
});

it('We can check if the consumer called the class constructor', () => {
  const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer();
  expect(SoundPlayer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});

it('We can check if the consumer called a method on the class instance', () => {
  const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer();
  const coolSoundFileName = 'song.mp3';
  soundPlayerConsumer.playSomethingCool();
  expect(mockPlaySoundFile.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual(coolSoundFileName);
});
```

system under test dependency

```
export default class SoundPlayer {
    constructor() {
      this.foo = 'bar';
    }
  
    playSoundFile(fileName) {
      console.log('Playing sound file ' + fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code under test in your question instead of a link

Comment: it's literally a copy of what's on the Jest site at https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks